# How to Solve $2.3856 + \log r = \log(364r - 363)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am solving geometric sequence and series problem, but got stuck on the logarithm part.  we haven't tackled logarithm yet so this is supposed to be a challenge problem.  can anyone advise on how to proceed.  here is the equation i'm stuck at:

$$2.3856 + \log r = \log(364r - 363)$$

Obviously, I need to get the value of $r$ here, but can't figure out how since logarithm is confusing me.

Comment: Hint: Substract $\log r$ on both sides. $2.3856  = \log(364r - 363)-\log r$ Then use a logarithm law: $2.3856  = \log(\frac{364r - 363}r)$ Can you proceed ?

Comment: what kind of $\log$ is this?

Comment: @callculus, yeah i think i got the rest covered.  thanks so much.

Comment: @RobinNico You are welcome. You can post your (intermediate) steps or results if you like.

Answer (score 1):

> Solve $r$ out of:
>
> $$a+\ln(r)=\ln(br+c)$$
>
> Using:
>
> - $$\exp\left[\ln(x)\right]=e^{\ln(x)}=x$$
> - $$\exp\left[x+y\right]=e^{x+y}=e^x\cdot e^y$$

---

So:

$$a+\ln(r)=\ln(br+c)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\exp\left[a+\ln(r)\right]=\exp\left[\ln(br+c)\right]\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\exp\left[a\right]\cdot\exp\left[\ln(r)\right]=\exp\left[\ln(br+c)\right]\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\exp\left[a\right]\cdot r=br+c\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\exp\left[a\right]\cdot r-br=c\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$r(\exp\left[a\right]-b)=c\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$r=\frac{c}{\exp\left[a\right]-b}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Rewrite your equation as $a+\log r=\log(br-c)$. Moving some terms around, $$a=\log(br - c) - \log r=\log( (br - c) / r ) = \log( b - c/r ).$$
Can you finish the rest?

Comment: yeah, i think i can handle the rest.  thanks so much.